# Configuring web server for laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, webserver

I'm using isp config but all my larval stuff is in a public folder and iso config points to a web folder.

Does anyone know how I can go about changing this?

Comment: Yup! You read the manual/documentation http://laravel.com/docs/configuration

Comment: I want to change it in isp config not in larval config, thanks

Comment: It depends on the options your ISP is giving you or better said the permissions. If they let you change the root to `/the/regular/path/public` you are there.

Comment: How would I do that in isp config? I have full permissions.

Comment: I recon it runs on Apache?

Comment: You need to be able to set the webroot of your current site to /public that's all. But I guess the webserver is shared by multiple users or do you have a VPS?

Comment: It's on my local machine. How would I set the webfoot? Should I put something in PHP open_basedir?

Comment: Check Antonio's answer below!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ISPConfig:

1) Select the site

2) Choose options

3) In the Apache Directives box type the full path of your Document Root pointing to /public:

```
DocumentRoot "/the/absolute/path/of/the/laravel/directory/public"
```